# Modulo calculation by theorems

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that the order of $Z_n$ is $t$: 
A) Calculate $a^t \mod n$ for an integer $a$ which is co-prime $n$ 
B) If ed = tk+1 and $c ≡m^e \mod n$ for some integers m,e,d,t.
Calculate $c^d \mod n$

Comment: This is not a discrete logarithm problem. That is about calculating $t$ if you only know $a$ and $x\equiv a^t\equiv n$. Also, if you know that the order of the group is $t$, then any element raised to power $t$ is trivial by Lagrange.

Comment: What about B part? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply Chinese Remainder Theorem on the prime-power factors of $n$.

Comment: And for part B?

Comment: @hmffa What have you tried? Do you know what Euler's theorem is? Side note: In general, avoid adding new parts to an existing question.

Comment: Yes but how does it work for part B? I was able to solve first part but what about the second? can you refer me to a page so I can Understand?